# Error when casting a reference parameter with dynamic_cast in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reference, open-closed-principle

I'm studying the book Agile Software Development by Robert C. Martin.
In an example on the Open-Closed Principle I had a problem with the dynamic_cast <>.

the example is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Shape {
public:
    virtual void Drow() const = 0;
    virtual bool Precedes(const Shape & s) const = 0;

    bool operator<(const Shape &s){ return Precedes(s);};
};

template<typename T>
class Lessp {
public:
    bool operator()(const T i , const T j) {return (*i) < (*j);}
};


void DrowAllShape(vector<Shape*> &vect){

    vector<Shape*> list = vect;

    sort(list.begin(),
        list.end(),
        Lessp<Shape*>());

    vector<Shape*>::const_iterator i;

    for(i = list.begin(); i != list.end()  ;i++){
        (*i)->Drow();
    }
}

class Square : public Shape{
    public :
        virtual void Drow() const{};
        virtual bool Precedes(const Shape& s) const;
};

class Circle : public Shape{
    public :
    virtual void Drow() const{};
    virtual bool Precedes(const Shape& s) const;
};

bool Circle::Precedes(const Shape& s) const {
    if (dynamic_cast<Square*>(s)) // ERROR : 'const Shape' is not a pointer
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

and i get error in the method Precedes of Circle
what is the problem ??

Comment: What is unclear in the error message? `s` is a const reference to `Shape`, and `dynamic_cast` requires a pointer as argument. Did you want to write `dynamic_cast<Shape*>(&s);`?

Comment: `dynamic_cast<Square*>(s)` -> `dynamic_cast<const Square*>(&s)`. You can also cast to a const ref `dynamic_cast<const Square&>(s)`, but the only indication of failure you'll get is a `bad_cast` exception.

Comment: If this listing is from a book, something is terribly wrong with the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dynamic_cast` to:

1. cast a pointer to another pointer (needs to be `const`-correct also).
2. cast a reference to another reference (needs to be `const`-correct also).

You can't use it to:

1. cast a pointer to a rereference, or
2. cast a reference to a pointer.

For that reason,

```
dynamic_cast<Square*>(s)
```

is wrong.

You can use

```
if ( dynamic_cast<Square const*>(&s) )
```

to resolve the compiler error.

You may use use `dynamic_cast<Square const&>(s)` (cast a reference) but that requires a `try`/`catch` block.

```
try 
{
    auto x = dynamic_cast<Square const&>(s);
}
catch ( std::bad_cast )
{
    return false;
}

// No exception thrown.
return true;
```